# Splitting of $2$ in a cubic extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $X^3-3X+1=0$. How does the prime $2$ split in $L$? I have figured out that either $2=\mathfrak{P}$ or $2=\mathfrak{P}\mathfrak{Q}\mathfrak{R}$. I guess it is the second form, but I do not know how to find the prime divisors.

Comment: Hint: $x^3-3x+1$ is irreducible modulo two.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Dedekind's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/836795/11619)? You need that to apply the above hint.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Since $x^3-3x+1$ is irreducible mod $2$, $2$ is inert in $L$. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Correct. Unless you think your question has a duplicate somewhere, please consider posting that as an answer. That way you get a bit more feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of $X^3-3X+1$ is $81 = 9^2$, so the splitting field is $L = \Bbb Q[X]/(X^3-3X+1)$. Let $t \in L$ with $t^3-3t+1=0$. Let $\alpha, \beta \in L$ be the remaining two roots.

Then $X^3-3X+1 = (X-t)(X^2+tX+(t^2-3)) = (X-t)(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)$, so:
$$(X-\alpha)(X-\beta) = X^2 + tX + (t^2-3)$$

From Vieta, we have $t+\alpha+\beta = 0$, so $\alpha+\beta = -t$.

Its discriminant is $81 = 9^2$, so:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)(\alpha-\beta) &=& 9 \\
(t^2 + tt + (t^2-3))(\alpha-\beta) &=& 9 \\
(3t^2-3)(\alpha-\beta) &=& 9 \\
(t^2-1)(\alpha-\beta) &=& 3 \\
\end{array}$$

To find the inverse of $t^2-1$, we calculate the characteristic polynomial of the matrix of multiplication by $t^2-1$, with basis $\{1, t, t^2\}$:

- $1 \times (t^2-1) = -1 + 0t + t^2$
- $t \times (t^2-1) = t^3 - t = 3t - 1 - t = 2t - 1 = -1 + 2t + 0t^2$
- $t^2 \times (t^2-1) = 2t^2 - t = 0 + (-1)t + 2t^2$

So the matrix is:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

whose characteristic polynomial is $(-1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)^2+1 = -\lambda^3+3\lambda^2-3 = \lambda(3\lambda-\lambda^2)-3$.

Therefore:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(t^2-1)(3(t^2-1)-(t^2-1)^2)-4 &=& 0 \\
\dfrac3{t^2-1} &=& 3(t^2-1)-(t^2-1)^2 \\
&=& 2t^2+t-4
\end{array}$$

So:
$$\alpha - \beta = \frac3{t^2-1} = 2t^2+t-4$$

And we conclude:

- $\alpha = \dfrac12 [(-t) + (2t^2+t-4)] = t^2-2$
- $\beta = (t^2-2)-(2t^2+t-4) = -t^2-t+2$

Now to calculate the relevant discriminant, we take the squared determinant of:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t & t^2 \\
1 & t^2-2 & -t^2-t+4 \\
1 & -t^2-t+2 & t+2
\end{bmatrix}$$

whose determinant is $-9$, so the discriminant is $81$.

So potential additional integers have the form $\dfrac13(a+bt+ct^2)$ with $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2\}$.

So I wrote a program to check:

```
(21:43) gp > f=(a,b,c)->charpoly([a,-c,-b;b,a+3*c,3*b-c;c,b,a+3*c])
%30 = (a,b,c)->charpoly([a,-c,-b;b,a+3*c,3*b-c;c,b,a+3*c])
(21:43) gp > for(i=0,2,for(j=0,2,for(k=0,2,print(f(i/3,j/3,k/3)))))
x^3
x^3 - 2*x^2 + x - 1/27
x^3 - 4*x^2 + 4*x - 8/27
x^3 - 1/3*x + 1/27
x^3 - 2*x^2 + x - 1/9
x^3 - 4*x^2 + 13/3*x - 19/27
x^3 - 4/3*x + 8/27
x^3 - 2*x^2 + 1/3*x + 1/27
x^3 - 4*x^2 + 4*x - 8/9
x^3 - x^2 + 1/3*x - 1/27
x^3 - 3*x^2 + 8/3*x - 17/27
x^3 - 5*x^2 + 7*x - 19/9
x^3 - x^2 + 1/9
x^3 - 3*x^2 + 8/3*x - 19/27
x^3 - 5*x^2 + 22/3*x - 71/27
x^3 - x^2 - x + 19/27
x^3 - 3*x^2 + 2*x - 1/3
x^3 - 5*x^2 + 7*x - 73/27
x^3 - 2*x^2 + 4/3*x - 8/27
x^3 - 4*x^2 + 5*x - 17/9
x^3 - 6*x^2 + 32/3*x - 136/27
x^3 - 2*x^2 + x - 1/27
x^3 - 4*x^2 + 5*x - 53/27
x^3 - 6*x^2 + 11*x - 17/3
x^3 - 2*x^2 + 8/9
x^3 - 4*x^2 + 13/3*x - 37/27
x^3 - 6*x^2 + 32/3*x - 152/27
```

As one can see, the only integer polynomial is $x^3$ which corresponds to $0$. So we conclude that $\mathcal O_L = \Bbb Z[t] = \Bbb Z[X]/(X^3-3X+1)$.

And finally to see the behaviour of $(2)$:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal O_L / 2 \mathcal O_L
&=& \Bbb Z[X]/(X^3-3X+1,2) \\
&=& \Bbb F_2[X]/(X^3-3X+1)
\end{array}$$

which is a field, as $X^3-3X+1 \in \Bbb F_2[X]$ is irreducible, as the comments have pointed out.

Therefore $(2)$ is a prime in $\mathcal O_L$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Good job adding a proof for the fact that the powers of a root of this give an integral basis.

Comment: FWIW the roots of this cubic are $2\cos(2\pi/9)$, $2\cos(4\pi/9)$ and $2\cos(8\pi/9)$. It appears frequently on our site, use [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E3-3x%2B1%24&p=1). It is one of the two famous cubics with the property that if $r$ is a root so is $r^2-2$. The other involves seventh roots of unity whereas this is about ninth roots of unity.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: How does one find these exact solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Use this proposition from p. 47 of *Algebraic Number Theory* by Neukirch: Let $L/K$ be a separable extension of number fields and let $\mathcal{o}$ and $\mathcal{O}$ be the rings of integers of $K$ and $L$, respectively. Assume that $L=K(\theta)$ for some $\theta\in\mathcal{O}$ with minimal polynomial over $K$ being $p(X)\in\mathcal{o}[X]$, then we have:

> **(8.3) Proposition.** Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{o}$ which is relatively prime to the conductor $\mathfrak{F}$ of $\mathcal{o}[\theta]$, and let
>   $$
>   \overline{p}(X)=\overline{p}_1(X)^{e_1}\cdots\overline{p}_r(X)^{e_r}
> $$
>   be the factorization of the polynomial $\overline{p}(X)=p(X)\pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$ into irreducibles $\overline{p}_i(X)=p_i(X)\pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$ over the residue class field $\mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p}$, with all $p_i(X)\in\mathcal{o}[X]$ monic. Then
>   $$
>   \mathfrak{P}_i=\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}+p_i(\theta)\mathcal{O},\quad i=1,\ldots,r,
> $$
>   are the different prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}$ above $\mathfrak{p}$. The inertia degree $f_i$ of $\mathfrak{
> P}_i$ is the degree of $\overline{p}_i(X)$, and one has
>   $$
>   \mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{P}^{e_1}_1\cdots\mathfrak{P}^{e_r}_r.
> $$

Now we apply this to our problem.

In our problem $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a root of $p(X)=X^3-3X+1$. $\mathcal{o}=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$. The minimal polynomial of $\theta\in\mathcal{O}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $p(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Let $\mathfrak{p}=2\mathbb{Z}$. Since the conductor of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ itself, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is relatively prime to it. Now $\overline{p}(X)=p(X)\pmod{2}=X^3-3X+1\pmod{2}$. $\overline{p}(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ because it is of degree $3$ and has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Whence the factorization of $\overline{p}(X)$ into irreducibles over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is just itself, namely
$$
  \overline{p}(X)=X^3-3X+1\pmod{2}.
$$
Notice that $X^3-3X+1\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is monic. Then
$$
\mathfrak{P}=\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}+p(\theta)\mathcal{O}=2\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}[\theta]+0\mathbb{Z}[\theta]=2\mathbb{Z}[\theta]
$$
is the only prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ above $2\mathbb{Z}$. The inertia degree of $2\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ is the degree of $X^3-3X+1\pmod{2}$, i.e. $3$, and one has
$$
  2\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}[\theta].
$$
In particular, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, i.e. $2$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$.